# CSS3 text-shadow distorts/pixelates in all IE browsers (see screenshot pls)

Tags: internet-explorer, frontend, css

I just put text shadow on an element and it looks fine in all browsers except any IE.

[image]

See the black pixles around the text?

```
color: #68C3C7;
font-family: "Hoefler Text",Baskerville,"Big Caslon","Adobe Garamond Pro",Georgia,Palatino,"Times New Roman",serif;
font-size: 30px;
letter-spacing: 1.2px;
line-height: 30px;
padding: 20px 0 0;
text-align: center;    
text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #999999;
filter: dropshadow(color=#999999, offx=1, offy=1);
```

Comment: IE does not support CSS3 `text-shadow` until version 10. That property cannot be the cause of the problem here - rather, it could be your filter.

Comment: Make sure Hardware acceleration is enabled on your IE, other than that, I cannot think of any reason.

Comment: Frankly, I'd just drop the `filter` style, and let users of IE live without shadowed text. It's not critical to the functioning of the page, so they won't be losing out from not having it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of  IE's `chroma & drop shadow` filter. Check this: http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2011/04/14/css3-text-shadow-can-it-be-done-in-ie-without-javascript/

Here's some example code:

```
color: #68C3C7;
font-family: "Hoefler Text",Baskerville,"Big Caslon","Adobe Garamond Pro",Georgia,Palatino,"Times New Roman",serif;
font-size: 30px;
letter-spacing: 1.2px;
line-height: 30px;
padding: 20px 0 0;
text-align: center;    
text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #999999;
background-color: white;
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Chroma(Color=white)
        progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.DropShadow(OffX=1, OffY=1, Color=#99999);
```

Answer (score 0):

there is the possibility that you need an extra argument for ie8:

```
.shadow {
/* For IE 8 */
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=4, Direction=135, Color='#000000')";
/* For IE 5.5 - 7 */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=4, Direction=135, Color='#000000');
```

}